# Why doesn't CiviCase API filter by case status when the client is specified?

Tags: api, civicase

This seems like a bug.  I encountered it on Joomla with 4.6.8 and reproduced on the demo server.

If I create a case and change the status to "Urgent", then use the API (including API explorer), it seems to filter properly on status_id and is_deleted UNTIL I also add contact_id (Case Client).  Then it returns the case regardless of its status.  (I didn't test whether it works correctly with is_deleted).

Comment: You could turn on CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY and see what the difference in queries is: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-SettingswhichmodifyCiviCRMbehaviorfordebugging

Answer (score 2):

While I can see this is an older issue I have the same problem in Drupal 7.41 and Civi 4.6.10. I found that this is no longer an issue in Drupal 7 Civi 4.7.27 (I just verified on the demo site!) If we aren't able to upgrade in the near future, I'll get around to looking at the log query (hopefully it doesn't come to that ;)